# Marketing cloud Email GET Rest Api (FuelSDK) returns 404

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

Here is a MCV:

```
    let options = {
        auth: {
            clientId: '<ClientId goes here>',
            clientSecret: '<ClientSecret goes here>'
        }
    };

    const RestClient = new FuelRest(options);
    options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: '/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:extern_id123/deliveryRecords/b648d03asdd6-af44-4564-8a3ad123d-a8f4caddadsa2512f7',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    return RestClient.get(options);
```

Im getting a 404 response code from this request. Is the last parameter of the URI suppose to be 'RecipientSendId' because the docs don't say if the last parameter is that? Also why am I getting a 404 response?

Link to docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSendsDeliveryRecords.htm

Answer (score -1):

The last parameter is recipientSendId.  This is returned in the response from triggering the send as both the requestId and recipientSendId (they are alwasy the same).

Either the external key or the recipientSendId is incorrect.  I see a 404 in either case.  I have tested sends with unencoded special characters in the uri and the ones that should work, do (:, -, _).

FuelSDK might be doing something with the request causing it to fail.  Have you tried making an api call via Postman or Insomnia and if so do you see the same result?

Comment: This doesn't feel like a complete answer. Are you certain that FuelSDK isn't making a substitution? Why is this syntax given in the official documentation? How can OP resolve their issue?